# Deep learning network to detect activity in videos

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a project to create a model that detects the type of activity two people in a video are doing. For example, let's consider a data set consisting of videos where the two people are boxing, wrestling, jumping, and even just talking with each other. How can I create a model to distinguish these activities from each other.

In particular, what kind of features should be extracted from the videos ? Should I use a pre-trained model with image-net weights etc. I am not sure where to begin. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest starting reading academic papers to get a sense of it.
This might be a good start; though it might be a little bit overwhelming if you are a beginner.

if you want to start exploring a collection of related papers/repositories, this is suggested: [link](https://github.com/SHI-Labs/Activity-Recognition).

If you want to start hands-on: this repository might be a good choice, it is advanced a collection of related implementations for such tasks: [link](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmaction2)

Here is also some benchmark that might be useful to follow: [link](https://paperswithcode.com/task/activity-recognition)